# Can Orca be used to operate on a DolphinDB stream table?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dolphindb

I was trying to append data to a stream table through the Orca API (pandas project of DolphinDB).

It seems that it doesn't work. Will Orca support operations on streams tables?

e.g.

```
orca.load_table(THE_STREAM_TABLE)
```

is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe read_share_table is for reading stream table:

```
orca.read_shared_table(THE_STREAM_TABLE)
```